# Some pdf files are not loading completely in chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, pdf

I have about 100 pdf files on the site and before yesterday all of them worked fine.

Starting yesterday some files would not load completely and only the first page would show up in chrome.

Few things to note:

1. All pdfs still work fine in all browsers except chrome.
2. I copied all files and database to the staging site and all pdfs work fine in all browsers including chrome. The staging site is on the same server.
3. Some times files that don't load would load, but then would be broken again. I couldn't pinpoint the reason why it would happen.
4. There is no code that creates/shows pdfs, the link that opens pdf just points to actual pdf location on the server.
5. The only thing that shows up in the console log when pdf doesn't load is a warning below:

`` A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at "" was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032. ``

I've tried adding cookieSameSite="Strict" and Lax, but it didn't resolve the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unless you actually wrote the PDF rendering code in Chrome (in which case we'd like to see a [mcve]), this question is about general software (mis)behavior,

Comment: Hi, it's software (mis)behavior. Do I have to change my question/tags or should I just remove it since I found the fix?

Comment: Your fix is to not use Chrome :P General software questions go on [Super User](https://superuser.com), on Stack Overflow only programming questions are on topic.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to figure out the issue, but after I changed code to open pdf with Asp.Net the issue got fixed.

Here is a sample of the code I added:

```
Response.Clear();
string filePath = "/downloads/" + Request.QueryString["file"];
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.WriteFile(filePath);
Response.End();
```